# Bean property list definition in JavaConfig class

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to convert my context.xml configuration file to pure javaConfig and for the most part i think i'd found my answers but one thing exactly is a black magic for me.

My context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd     
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.properties"
        system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE" />

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="mypackage.servlets.dao,mypackage.servlets" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <alias name="${dao}" alias="daoType"/>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I've managed to replace everything but:

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and my resulting JavaConfig class looks like this:

```
package mypackage.servlets;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView;

import mypackage.servlets.dao.LibraryDAO;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("mypackage.servlets.dao,mypackage.servlets")
@EnableWebMvc
public class ConfigClass {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    public LibraryDAO MyServiceAlias(@Value("${dao}") String qualifier) {
        return (LibraryDAO) context.getBean(qualifier);
    }

    @Bean
    public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver myContentNegotiation()
    {
        return new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2JsonView myJackson()
    {
        return new MappingJackson2JsonView();
    }
}
```

My tries to find an answer for my question missed my point, becouse `@Bean` properties are often misstreated as properties in `app.properties` file. I'm rather new to SPRING and trying to understand javaConfig class. I've found out, that simple dependency can be injected as this:

```
@Bean
    public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver myContentNegotiation()
    {
        return new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver(myJackson());
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2JsonView myJackson()
    {
        return new MappingJackson2JsonView();
    }
```

but in this case my IDE throws an error that `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` has only default constructor. And summarizing, I'd like to know how to define this `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` in javaConfig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.setViewResolvers(list), which accepts list of view resolvers. Please check below configuration.

```
 * Configure ContentNegotiationManager
 */
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true).defaultContentType(
            MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
}

/*
 * Configure ContentNegotiatingViewResolver
 */
@Bean
public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
    resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);

    // Define all possible view resolvers
    List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();
    resolvers.add(jsonViewResolver());

    resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
    return resolver;
}

 /*
 * Configure View resolver to provide JSON output using JACKSON library to
 * convert object in JSON format.
 */
@Bean
public ViewResolver jsonViewResolver() {
    return new JsonViewResolver();
}
```

Check the [this](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-contentnegotiatingviewresolver-example/) tutorial here.